# Does jQuery still have XSS vulnerabilities when we upgrade the version with jQuery Migrate and do not replace the deprecated methods?

Tags: jquery, security, xss, jquery-migrate

The website below says that jQuery Migrate restores the deprecated methods which older jQuery has.
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate

Does jQuery still have XSS vulnerabilities when we upgrade the version to latest 3.5.1 and do not replace the deprecated methods to new ones?

I looked for the information, but I could not find good websites.
It would be very grateful if you give me some information about it.

Comment: What do deprecated methods have to do with XSS?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I misunderstood. It seems that if we upgrade to 3.5.1, we have no XSS vulnerabilities regardless of deprecated methods.